# Why is nature not studied in the way the Rambam recommends?

Tags: rambam, science, yeshiva-school

Considering the [Rambam recommends](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/1102.htm) observing nature to see the divine wisdom therein and develop a love of God, if so, why is this not encouraged in the yeshivas with this outlook?

The few yeshivos that study science do this primarily as part of an academic curriculum not as a way to appreciate the wisdom of God manifested in nature. I am asking specifically about the latter form of studying science.

Comment: Actually it is encouraged in some Yeshivas. Not all Yeshivas nowadays stick to tradition, unfortunately.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45779/discussion-on-question-by-ray-is-there-a-mitzva-to-study-science).

Comment: Here's an example of a yeshiva teaching science specifically as a way to apprciate God: http://yeshiva.edu/ABOUTUS/Marabumaasecha/tabid/419/Default.aspx

Comment: `why is this not encouraged in the yeshivas at all? the few yeshivas that study science...` You seem to be conflating _encouraging_ study with _incorporating_ the study in a curriculum. Consider clarifying what you are trying to ask.

Comment: `Considering the Rambam recommends observing nature to see the divine wisdom therein and develop a love of God, if so, why is this not encouraged in the yeshivas with this outlook?` In yeshivot with which outlook? The approach that science should be studied? Presumably those do study science, by definition. Those with the outlook that one should love God? Which Yeshiva would disagree? Consider editing to clarify what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Because other Rishonim argued on the Rambam?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Such as...? (Not that i'm doubting you).

Comment: @mevaqesh The Rosh? Rashba?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Which statements from either, indicate opposition to arousing one's love for God from marveling at the wonders of nature?

Comment: Vote to close as Jews not Judaism?

Comment: What does "with this outlook" refer to? Can you document or otherwise substantiate your claim about yeshivas in that category?

Comment: I think nature throughout the time period of the yeshiva system has proven to be more of an issue raising questions about God as the creator than it has been a means to appreciate what He has done.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question, since the Rambam does _not_ suggest studying these topics in public (Yesodei Hatorah 4(10)). On the contrary, he forbids it.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps it is not taught due to all the atheist professors/scientists using science as a platform to spread their views.

for example Biologist Richard Dawkins who wrote book after book and each one is titled like an argument against God.

update: i spoke to a yeshiva educator here in israel (yehuda shwab) who confirmed this is the reason the whole area is avoided

Comment: In my experience the number of professors/scientists who do this is tiny.  Just the ones who do are very vocal.

Comment: Besides for being mere speculation, [I already noted](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/45779?m=32499243#32499243) that someone with a blooming interest in the natural sciences is unlikely to turn to books about atheism. Your defense was only that [books about atheism are very popular](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/45779?m=32500379#32500379). This is totally irrelevant, as it has nothing to do with learning science, and hence nothing to do with this question. Books about dieting are also very popular, but there is no reason to assume that studying science will cause dieting.

Comment: @Heshy i disagree. take darwinian evolution for example. the "belief" that random mutations is capable of engineering life is accepted almost universally within the scientific community. yet there is no proof of this besides being total nonsense.

Comment: Was Shwab speaking about his own practices, was he speculating about the practices of others, or does he have factual information concerning others? If the latter, which others does he have information about?

Comment: @ray In your response to Heshy you once again conflate the mechanism of change in a species, with the motivation for such a mechanism. That is, the theory of evolution and atheism.

Comment: @mevaqesh at the heart of darwinian evolution is RANDOM mutations.

Comment: There are plenty of religious scientists (especially in Israel) who can teach science in yeshivot without trying to push an atheist agenda.   And how better to combat atheist notions than by showing the right way to combine torah with science.

Comment: @ray at the heart of Monopoly is a RANDOM roll of the dice.  Why is this any different?  Just because something is distributed as you would statistically expect doesn't mean Hashem is not controlling it.

Comment: @Heshy true. but truly random processes produce nonsense.

Comment: @Nic maybe it is a kind of inertia from the haskala movement where there were two camps. the yeshiva and the maskilim/scientists. the yeshiva people were on the defensive at the time since most yeshiva students who started to learn science went off completely

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a reason that yeshivas are designated for study of specifically Jewish texts. There are many things, including science, that can expand our appreciation of Hashem but aren't taught in yeshivot. Furthermore, a yeshiva is not supposed to be a place whereby all life skills are acquired e.g. learning a skill for earning a living, which is also crucially important.

Another reason is that most Rabbanim are not experts in the sciences so it seems inappropriate to ask yeshivas to teach/encourage study in this area specifically. In depth study in science is something that can be acquired in university and personal study. Yeshivot encourage dialectic learning in chavruta, this kind of learning is unique to yeshivas and often gets increasingly difficult when one leaves yeshiva - so utilizing this time for study of Jewish texts in chavruta is a prominent method of study.

What is a shame, from my experience, is that many Rabbanim don't have a basic understanding of science and relevant sources in Jewish literature to discuss the interaction between Torah and Science. Meaning, that once a yeshiva student leaves the yeshiva environment and may study science, the Rabbanim that he relied on previously don't necessarily know how to answer the questions that he may have, and rather than tackle them head on, they are involved in apologetics.

This is, in a sense, a cost benefit analysis; yeshivot would rather not teach outright science than talk about it in a mediocre non-expert manner, where they could run into problems.

Comment: so you are saying it is just a case of priority, that torah study takes priority? but wouldnt having an appreciation of the divine wisdom increase one's zeal for torah study as the rambam says.

Comment: Yes, in a yeshiva the particular style of Torah study takes priority - especially honing in on textual skills in Jewish texts. When mainstream yeshivot begin learning mussar, chassidut, Tanach, etc. then maybe branching to areas such as science would take place (if Rabbi's become qualified to do so, etc.). Aside from 'having an appreciation of the divine' (which they can also get through learning 'how He works', via textual study), improving your middot, learning a trade, improving interpersonal skills, etc are also important. Theres a time and a place.

Comment: but why is this not encouraged?